# Swift_Mailer auth and send successfull but no email

Tags: symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm working on a Symfony project, and I'm trying to send an email from a custom SMTP (from o2switch) with Swift Mailer.

My parameters.yml is configured with good values, and when I try to send an email I can retrieve this log :

```
++ Starting Swift_SmtpTransport<br />
&lt;&lt; 220-tournevis.o2switch.net ESMTP Exim 4.87 #1 Mon, 23 May 2016 17:27:32 +0200 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
&gt;&gt; EHLO MY_IP
&lt;&lt; 250-MY_CUSTOM_SMTP Hello MY_IP [MY_IP]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
&gt;&gt; AUTH LOGIN
&lt;&lt; 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
&gt;&gt; cC5jb2xsaW5hQG15YmV0ZnJpZW5kLmZy
&lt;&lt; 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
&gt;&gt; Nk9oVGJIa1ZwSH4t
&lt;&lt; 235 Authentication succeeded
++ Swift_SmtpTransport started<br />
&gt;&gt; MAIL FROM:&lt;MY_EMAIL_FROM@EMAIL.FR&gt;
&lt;&lt; 250 OK
&gt;&gt; RCPT TO:&lt;MY_EMAIL@gmail.com&gt;
&lt;&lt; 250 Accepted
&gt;&gt; DATA
&lt;&lt; 354 Enter message, ending with &quot;.&quot; on a line by itself
&gt;&gt; 
.
&lt;&lt; 250 OK id=1b4rlU-004H3I-HE
Successfull.++ Stopping Swift_SmtpTransport<br />
&gt;&gt; QUIT
&lt;&lt; 221 MY_CUSTOM_SMTP closing connection
++ Swift_SmtpTransport stopped<br />
```

So I can red auth login is OK, sending is OK, but I never receive any email..

Any ideas ? My problem is from Symfony ? My custom SMTP ? My server ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try with mailtrap.io and discard server problems with the sending.

In past i have some troubles sending from a command because the transport doesn't close never and the server close the socket and i didn't have any error.